# How to Reset/reload the UI Page Controller views in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I am looking to how to reload the UI page controller.
On a table VC I have added UIHeaderView and embedded the UIPage VC.
Page VC is loading images dynamically from firebase.
First time it is loading the right set of images but when on the table VC I selecting other cel the Page VC need to refresh its data.
How to achieve this functionality
Here is the coed I have written for PAGE VC

```
//-----PAGE VC CODE------
import UIKit
import Firebase

protocol ProductImagesPageVCDelegate: class
{
    func setupPageController(numberOfPages: Int)
    func turnPageController(to index: Int)
}

class ProductImagesPageVC: UIPageViewController {

    var product: Product!

    weak var pageViewControllerDelegate: ProductImagesPageVCDelegate?

    struct StoryBoard {
        static let productImageVC = "ProductImageVC"
    }

    lazy var controllers: [UIViewController] = {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var controllers = [UIViewController]()

        if let imageLinks = self.product.imageLinks
        {
            for imageLink in imageLinks
            {
                let productImageVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: StoryBoard.productImageVC)
                controllers.append(productImageVC)
            }
        }

        self.pageViewControllerDelegate?.setupPageController(numberOfPages: controllers.count)

        return controllers
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

//        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
//            contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
//        } else {
//            automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
//        }
        automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
        dataSource = self
        delegate = self

        self.turnToPage(index: 0)


    }


    func turnToPage(index: Int)
    {
        let controller = controllers[index]
        var direction = UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward

        if let currentVC = viewControllers?.first
        {
            guard let currentIndex = controllers.index(of: currentVC) else {return}
            if currentIndex > index
            {
                direction = .reverse
            }
        }

        self.configuewDisplaying(viewController: controller)

        setViewControllers([controller], direction: direction, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func configuewDisplaying(viewController: UIViewController)
    {
        for (index, vc) in controllers.enumerated()
        {
            if viewController === vc {
                if let productImageVC = viewController as? ProductImageVC
                {
                    productImageVC.imageLink = self.product.imageLinks?[index]

                    self.pageViewControllerDelegate?.turnPageController(to: index)
                }
            }
        }
    }


}

extension ProductImagesPageVC: UIPageViewControllerDataSource
{
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        if let index = controllers.index(of: viewController)
        {
            if index < controllers.count - 1
            {
                return controllers[index + 1]
            }
        }


        return controllers.first
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        if let index = controllers.index(of: viewController)
        {
            if index > 0
            {
                return controllers[index - 1]
            }
        }

        return controllers.last
    }
}

extension ProductImagesPageVC: UIPageViewControllerDelegate
{

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionTo pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController]) {

        self.configuewDisplaying(viewController: pendingViewControllers.first as! ProductImageVC)
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {

        if !completed
        {
            self.configuewDisplaying(viewController: previousViewControllers.first as! ProductImageVC)
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: I have tried everything was not working. as they were referred to objective c or old swift versions

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

> let viewControllers: [UIViewControllers] = [UIViewController()]
>
> if let pageViewController = parentViewController as? UIPageViewController {
> pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)}